# Java Generic with 1 type parameter and 2 constraints

Tags: java, generics

I know it's possible to add multiple constraints to a Generic class definition, e.g.:

```
class Example<I extends Object & Comparable<Object>>{}
```

But I want a generic (`MyGeneric`) that takes another generic (`SomeGeneric<T>`) as its type parameter, and to constrain the type parameter (`T`) of that generic (e.g. `T extends SomeClass`).

Important, I need to know the types of both `SomeGeneric` and `SomeClass` from inside the class (`G` and `T` need to both be bound). For example, imagine something like this:

```
class MyGeneric<G extends SomeGeneric<T>, T extends SomeClass>
{
   public G returnSomeGenericImpl(){}
   public T returnSomeClassImpl(){}
}
```

**Question:**
The above works, but I would prefer if my class had only one type parameter, to make life easier for implementers of my class. Is there a way of doing this?

Something like this would be nice (but this particular code is incorrect):

```
class MyGeneric<G extends SomeGeneric<T extends SomeClass>>
{
   public G returnSomeGenericImpl(){}
   public T returnSomeClassImpl(){}
}
```

If I wasn't clear, I'll gladly try to clarify my intent.

Comment: I don't see how this could possibly work. If you never *specify* the concrete type `T`, how should the compiler guess it? If there's only a single option, then it's easy, but there usually isn't. And if you don't *care* about the specific type, then why not use a bounded wildcard type (or a local type parameter on the method).

Comment: @JoachimSauer are you saying that due to type erasure the compiler could enforce the constraint I want, but could not extract/know the type of the generic? for example, it can do `<G extends SomeGeneric<SomeClass>>` or even `<G extends SomeGeneric<? extends SomeClass>>`, but the type of `T` (`?` in this case) is not known.

Comment: @JoachimSauer regarding the second part of your comment, obviously I do care about the specific type as I would like to return an instance of it from `public T returnSomeClassImpl(){}`

Comment: @Bohemian specifying two types is generally no problem, but in this case it feels redundant to write `new Whatever<SomeGeneric<T>,T>()`, we're just repeating `T`. if it's not possible it's not possible, that was the point of the question

Comment: Well, if you want to bind `G extends SomeGeneric<T>` to `SomeGeneric<T>`, then maybe you can get rid of **`G`** altogether?

Comment: I had that at one stage, but then `public G returnSomeGenericImpl(){}` needs to be rewritten to `public SomeGeneric<T> returnSomeGenericImpl(){}`, which means if consumers of the class want to get the real type back they need to cast, e.g.: `ConcreteSomeGeneric<T> csg = (ConcreteSomeGeneric<T>)myGeneric.returnSomeGenericImpl()`. everything works at present, but I'm trying to make the user experience easier/less clunky

Comment: I had no idea Java had intersection types!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks impossible to achieve.

After reducing your type definition by one order by removing one type variable and trying to define it,

```
class G extends SomeGeneric<T extends SomeClass>{}
```

does not compile because the type parameter T is not bound with respect to an already defined type parameter. But, this works -

```
class G<T extends SomeClass> extends SomeGeneric<T>{}
```

So, I infer that the only way of parameterizing with two types is by declaring them up front.

Comment: @seeta when you write "So, I infer that the only way of parameterizing with two types is by declaring them up front." what do you mean by "up front"? the problem with defining a class up front is I would need to enforce that all necessary classes extend this class... which is not a solution. however "It looks impossible to achieve" sadly, I think I agree with

Comment: @nakosspy regarding "The class has two type parameters T and G. Both must be declared upfront", of course, nobody ever debated that. the question was about how java allows them to be declared.

Comment: @AlexAverbuch By up front, I meant declaring the parameters with the class name. As you wrote -      MyGeneric<G extends SomeGeneric<T>, T extends SomeClass>

Comment: @AlexAverbuch Would you want to accept the answer for closure?

Comment: I've (hesitantly) accepted your answer but mostly - as you say - for closure. I was hoping someone would have a better answer, along the lines of "no, it's not possible, and here's a detailed explanation of why" or "yes, here's a pattern you can use to achieve what you want"

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
class Test1<T extends List<? extends Number>> {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Test1<ArrayList<Number>>();  
        new Test1<ArrayList<Integer>>(); 
        new Test1<ArrayList<Object>>();  // compile error
    } 
}
```

Comment: could you please add some more explanation in this?So it'll be more helpful for me to follow this discussion

Comment: it says "allowed type is a List of Numbers"

Comment: please reread question: "Important, I need to know the types of both SomeGeneric and SomeClass from inside the class (G and T need to both be bound)"

Comment: If you need bindings for both, then they both have to be parameters. If the inner type isn't a parameter, then you can't bind it.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine this:

```
Type t = someClass();
Type g = someGeneric(t);

foobar(g,t)
```

compared to this

```
Type g = someGeneric(someClass());
foobar(g,?)
```

the second one is Evgeniy Dorofeev's solution.
You see the problem? You can't bind to a variable within an argument. Same with generics.
What you want to do is this

```
Type g = someGeneric(Type t = someClass());
foobar(g,t)
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but I don't think this qualifies as an answer. perhaps it's better to respond to @EvgeniyDorofeev as a comment on his answer..?